# Non Translation of Doctype Entities

Tags: android

I have a doctype entity defined:

```
<!DOCTYPE resources [
<!ENTITY appname "MyApp">
]>
```

Is there a way to make the entity non translatable or do I need to do it at every occurrence in the strings.xml like:

```
<string name="thanks">Thanks for trying <xliff:g id="myapp">&appname;</xliff:g></string>
```

Thanks in advance for all your help!